# Xamarin iOS application crash after update to iOS 17

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, ios17

I am developing a mobile app using Xamarin. This app worked well until the update to iOS 17. Since then I have an issue: if I launch the app directly to a physical device (typically an iPhone) it crashes after about one minute (both in debug and release mode). If I upload it on the app store and then execute from there it crashes immediately after the splash screen.
I don't get any errors (or if I get some I don't know where to look for them).
Has anyone had the same experience? Any advice is very useful.

I tried to follow some suggestion about clean & rebuild the code, i updated both Visual Studio and XCode to the latest version but the issue is still there.

These are the logs I found:

Time    Device Name Type    PID Tag Message
Oct 13 17:26:29 iPhone-Ludovico Notice  33  runningboardd(RunningBoard) [application<com.euklis.guestoncloud.iOS>:68117] termination reported by launchd (1, 7, 9)
Oct 13 17:26:29 iPhone-Ludovico Error   62  SpringBoard(KeyboardArbiter)    [<_UIKeyboardArbiter: 0x281e82e50; <<_UIKeyboardArbiter_ForSpringBoard: 0x282bc2160>; scene = <FBSScene: 0x280b11600; identifier: com.apple.UIKit.remote-keyboard; valid: YES> {
Oct 13 17:26:29 iPhone-Ludovico Notice  65  backboardd(BackBoardHIDEventFoundation) Removing client connection <BKHIDClientConnection: 0x10a7505d0; IOHIDEventSystemConnectionRef: 0x10a7f0d30; vpid: 68117(v319CA); taskPort: 0x3DE8B; bundleID: com.euklis.guestoncloud.iOS> for client: IOHIDEventSystemConnection uuid:33F11850-0E7C-4BE4-ABEF-B1D8CEDFE125 pid:68117 process:Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS type:Passive entitlements:0x0 caller:BackBoardServices:  + 336 attributes:{
Oct 13 17:26:29 iPhone-Ludovico Notice  65  backboardd(IOKit)   Connection removed: IOHIDEventSystemConnection uuid:33F11850-0E7C-4BE4-ABEF-B1D8CEDFE125 pid:68117 process:Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS type:Passive entitlements:0x0 caller:BackBoardServices:  + 336 attributes:{
Oct 13 17:26:29 iPhone-Ludovico Notice  62  SpringBoard(FrontBoard) [application<com.euklis.guestoncloud.iOS>:68117] Now flagged as pending exit for reason: workspace client connection invalidated
Oct 13 17:26:29 iPhone-Ludovico Notice  62  SpringBoard(FrontBoard) [application<com.euklis.guestoncloud.iOS>:68117] Workspace connection invalidated.
Oct 13 17:26:28 iPhone-Ludovico Notice  86  bluetoothd(CoreUtils)   SystemUI unknown identifier: 'sceneID:com.euklis.guestoncloud.iOS-default' / 'com.euklis.guestoncloud.iOS'

Thank you

Comment: You should look in the device logs and see what is going on. If it also crashes in debug mode, then you should have plenty of stack traces etc to go from to fix your issues.

Comment: Add logging to your app and you can also extract the crash info from the phone via Xcode

Comment: Here are some related issues on GitHub: [.NET Maui 7 app crashes on iOS 17](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/16316), [App startup crashes on iOS 17.0](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/issues/18964). You may take a look.